# Android: How can I fill a text box with text located in another activity?

Tags: android

I would like to createa dynamic text box that has the text filled by using text (a string variable) in a stub that I can edit later.

How would I go about doing this? Any code snippets or information would be appriciated because I'm kind of stuck about how to get the text from one activity in the text box of another, or how to make the text formatted in such a way that it can be located and used.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can use sendExtra like methods to communicate between the Activity. for Detail please refer to the developer.android.com

Answer (score 1):

Put your string in to bundle object using put extra. To retrieve call getIntent().getExtra() from second activity